# FATFS copy between Ramdisk(FMC) and SD(SPI) on STM32F4

Tags: stm32, sd, ram, fat

I am trying to solve this problem. I am using FATFS13 on my custom STM32F469 board and I am using the Standard Peripheral library.

I have connected 1MB of SRAM over the FMC bus, and an SD card over the SPI bus.
I can mount on both hardware a FAT file system, FAT12 on the RAM and FAT32 on the SD.
I tested SD cards up to 32GB so I can say that everything is working.
It's possible to manage files on each volume. I named them RAMDISK and SDCARD in the ffconf.h

Basically I want two drives so that the user can copy graphic files in the SRAM for a faster access during the execution of programs.

The problem is that when I try to copy a file from one drive to the other, it's copied only the first chunk of data. 
A single cycle:
- read from source
- copy to dest
- read from source
-> Error 9 on the source ((9) The file/directory object is invalid).

I tried to dig into the code, and with the debugger I noticed that after the write to the destination file when it's time to read the second chunk of data, the 'obj->fs->fs_type' of the source file is set to 0. So the validation fails.

I can't figure out why. Did you have a similar experience?

In order to avoid this error I need to have only one file opened a time, so I temporary solved the problem with this sequence:
- open source
- read chunck of data at offset
- close source
- open destination for append
- save chunk of data
- close destination.

In your experience is there a particular way to perform a correct copy on different volumes?

Thank you.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code, otherwise we cannot guess.

Comment: I don't think it's related to electrical engineering. Please try on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software error in code not provided in the question

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it's difficult to understand a problem from pieces of code, Just was wondering if someone has a similar problem. After a lot of tests and debug, I Probably understood the problem... 
Originally I put the two file systems FATFS into an array.

Since I have two drives I declared:
**FATFS FileSystems[FF_VOLUMES];**

Instead, I tried to declare two different structures like:

**FATFS FileSystemSD;**

**FATFS FileSystemRAM;**

Everything worked perfectly. The copy between the two volumes is OK now. 
So If I use those structures inside an array, somehow, somewhere, data are messed up if we access to files on different volumes at once.
I checked the indexes in the code but I didn't notice anything wrong.

So, for now, I can't figure out what is going on, I will do more tests but this solved my problem.